# MVC Change DefaultConnection

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-connection, webmatrix

Just for the hell of it, I decided I didn't want the Membership authorisation mechanism in MVC to use `Default Connection`, I wanted it to use a connection string I created called `Membership`.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Membership" 
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Development_Membership;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and created a transform in my `web.release.config` to change this to my production database, i.e.:

I changed the line in `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` to read:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Membership", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

However, when I deployed via the VS publish, I found that a dummy Default Connection had been revived and seems to being used as if I change it to a dummy string, membership breaks.

What's going on here, is it possible to get rid of `Default Connection`, or rather, use another, better named connection string?